# how to import excel form in informatica? I want to import data from excel form to informatica and finally insert into DB table

Tags: excel, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud, informatica-powerexchange

I want to import data from excel form to informatica and finally insert into DB table. the data in the excel is in key:value format(ex. name : "xyz"(in the next right cell)) how can i import that data such that the "Name" becomes the column name and "xyz" becomes the data in informatica source?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason the Excel file cannot be saved as a CSV first? If not, you'll an Excel connector. Then you will need to convert the rows to columns. There are a few approaches to that. Google them or search the Informatica Network.

Answer (score 0):

As i understood you want to convert {Name:value} pair in excel file to {Column:Row} in Informatica Source i have articulated input from your statement; Can you also propose your output for more clarification?

Input
Name1:"Value1"
Name2:"Value2"
Name3:"Value3"
Name3:"Value4"

Now, If you want to convert the file before importing it into informatica; there are multiple functions in Excel to perform Like(VLOOKUP,XLOOKUP) please try to explore these if it can make some use.

Please Refer below to split your values: 
https://www.excelfunctions.net/split-string-in-excel.html

Or there is one more way you can perform 
1. Import Excel file into informatica source with no changes in single column
2. Using Expression transformation - you can split the {name:value} pair into {Column:row} with regular expression(Refer infa sample workflow on pivot from google)

It can help with Output format as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer:

> Create first a temporary table e.g. `TMP_RAW_DATA` with one column.
>   load all the values as they are into that table.
>   now load your table from that `TMP_RAW_DATA table` using sql to your new table

Separate the Columns from the single raw data into multiple columns, then load them to your new table.

```
 SELECT 
        regexp_substr(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(value,'[A-Za-z0-9_-]+:',''), '(" ")+', '","'), '"', ''), '[^,]+', 1, 1) as COL_ONE,
        regexp_substr(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(value,'[A-Za-z0-9_-]+:',''), '(" ")+', '","'), '"', ''), '[^,]+', 1, 2) as COL_TWO,
        regexp_substr(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(value,'[A-Za-z0-9_-]+:',''), '(" ")+', '","'), '"', ''), '[^,]+', 1, 3) as COL_THREE 
 FROM  TMP_RAW_DATA
```

You will have two mappings

- one for loading the raw data as it is into one column
- two for loading from TMP_RAW_DATA table to your new table

[db <> fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9e8829b10aab112f8af505743b10d36d)